# How to display a list of dialogs with the last received or sent message?

Tags: php, sql

Tell me please, how to display a list of dialogs with the last received or sent message?

[image]

I tried it this way, but this is not the right solution:

```
$viewLastMsg = R::findAll('chats', 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');

foreach ($viewLastMsg as $vLM)
{
if(
    ($vLM->sender_type == 'user' && $vLM->sender_id == $_SESSION['logged_user']->id && $vLM->recipient_id == $bot->id)
    ||
    ($vLM->sender_type == 'bot'  && $vLM->sender_id == $bot->id && $vLM->recipient_id == $_SESSION['logged_user']->id)
)
{
    echo $vLM->message;
}
}
```

Perhaps using SQL query?

Comment: what framework is?

Comment: @flakerimi no framework, RedBean ORM

Comment: since it will return one record, why dont you use findOne and make condition to query

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$viewLastMsg = R::findAll('chats',

WHERE (sender_type=bot,...) 
OR (sender_type = user,...) ',
'ORDER BY id DESC');

foreach($viewLastMsg as $last):
echo $last->message;
endforeach;
```

Comment: This is a request for the last record.
I need a list of dialogs for each user.

Comment: I edited, check now, you limited to 1 on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the below

```
   SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * from your_table order by id
   ,send_time desc)
   LIMIT 1
```